# Make Div A The Same Height As Fluid Div B

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I'm kinda stuck on something... I'm trying to get `#right` to be the same height as `#left` but `#right` is fluid. How would I go about doing this?

```
 #container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#left {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
}

#right {
    background: #ccc;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 750px;
}
```

-

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        test
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is container div's end tag `</div>` ? What's the problem ? It works for me.

Comment: Oops. I'll fix that. And it works for me too. I was just trying to get #left to be the same height as #right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying a background image that's simulates a 100% height `#left`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        test
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        test<br />test
    </div>​
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/180x1/ccc/ccc.png) repeat-y;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    background: #ccc;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 750px;
    height; 100%;
}​
```

**Live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/TqKMW/
**More information about this trick**: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: The `#container` has no closing tag (thx to @Coder). Corrected the HTML markup additionally. Your welcome :)

Comment: Just one last thing, what if I wanted to add padding to the container?

Comment: Then adapting the background position is a good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/TqKMW/1/

Comment: Ah, that one was obvious. Should've seen it. :P Thanks. :)

Comment: `background: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/180x1/ccc/ccc.png) repeat-y 5px 0;` 5px to the right and 0 from top. Another way is to create an image which has a white border at the top, with, for example, 5px and a height of 250px for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `padding-bottom:10000px;margin-bottom:-10000px;` to each column and `overflow:hidden;` to the wrapper ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtkzZ/)):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        test<br>test
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    padding-bottom:10000px; /* Taller than tallest possible column */
    margin-bottom:-10000px; /* Negative version of #left{padding-bottom} */
}

#right {
    background: #ccc;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 750px;
    padding-bottom:10000px; /* Same as #left{padding-bottom} */
    margin-bottom:-10000px; /* Negative version of #left{padding-bottom} */
}
```

***Note:** This may not work in some older browsers, so make sure you check to make sure it works in the browsers you are required to support.*